# Apache POI - How to insert a hyperlink in the middle of a paragraph

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to insert a hyperlink in the middle of a paragraph. So far, I managed to add the `CTHyperlink` into the `CTP` of the `XWPFParagraph` and also add the `XWPFHyperlinkRun` into where I want it to be. However, the resulting document always places the hyperlink at the end of the paragraph. Is there any way to make the order of the xml elements correspond to the order of the runs?

I added this method into XWPFParagraph, which is what I'm using to insert the hyperlink:

```
    public XWPFHyperlinkRun insertNewHyperlinkRun(int pos, CTHyperlink ctHyperlink) {
    XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkRun = new XWPFHyperlinkRun(ctHyperlink, ctHyperlink.getRArray(0), this);
    int iPos = this.iruns.size();
    if (pos < this.runs.size()) {
      XWPFRun oldAtPos = (XWPFRun)this.runs.get(pos);
      int oldAt = this.iruns.indexOf(oldAtPos);
      if (oldAt != -1) {
        iPos = oldAt;
      }
    }

    this.iruns.add(iPos, hyperlinkRun);
    this.runs.add(pos, hyperlinkRun);
    return hyperlinkRun;
  }
```

I've already created ctHyperlink before calling this method:

```
                    CTHyperlink cLink = paragraph.getCTP().insertNewHyperlink(0);

                    cLink.setId(id);

                    //Create the linked text
                    CTText ctText=CTText.Factory.newInstance();
                    ctText.setStringValue("this is a inserted link");
                    CTR ctr=CTR.Factory.newInstance();
                    ctr.setTArray(new CTText[]{ctText});

                    CTRPr rpr = ctr.addNewRPr();

                    rpr.set(paragraph.getRuns().get(i).getCTR().getRPr());

                    CTString string = rpr.addNewRStyle();
                    string.setVal("Hyperlink");

                    //Insert the linked text into the link
                    cLink.setRArray(new CTR[]{ctr});

                    paragraph.insertNewHyperlinkRun(0, cLink);
```

Comment: `So far, I managed to add the CTHyperlink into the CTP of the XWPFParagraph` `<--` why tell when you can show (the code)? :D

Comment: Please show us some code.